# How to setup xfreerdp timeout?

Tags: timeout, freerdp

Using xfreerdp and CentOS 7.6
Command :

```
xfreerdp --ignore-certificate --authonly -u <username> -p <password> <ip>
```

How to setup time of 1 second. If fail to stop? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use `/timeout:<time in ms>`